# Rally edit cardboard displayed field

Tags: field, edit, rally

Created a Task board using SDK 2.0 rallycardboard. Trying to allow edit of ToDo field directly from card, but can't find example or method to use. Fields like Name and Owner are editable. My next task will be to group by Story and Feature....

Answer (score 0):

Currently the fields that can be edited on cards cards are limited. Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086821/is-it-possible-to-convert-the-old-rally-task-board-to-the-new-cardboard)

```
var myCardConfig = {
               xtype: 'rallycard',
               fields: ['ToDo', 'Estimate', 'WorkProduct'],
               editable: true
        }
```

`editable: true` makes only Name editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the actual editing implementation for the cards:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.CardEditing

It's marked as a private class in the docs, but that's ok.  If you take a look at the source:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/source/CardEditing.html#Rally-ui-cardboard-plugin-CardEditing

You can see that the _getEditorFieldConfigs method returns all the editors, and currently only Name and PlanEstimate are included by default.  Rally.ui.Card instantiates this editing plugin inside its setupPlugins method.

You can probably extend Rally.ui.Card with your own class and then inside setupPlugins pass your own editor fields for the various additional fields you'd like to edit.  The plugin was designed to be generic but we just never went back and enabled editing for the other fields...